# Tomcat remote deploy with Intellj IDEA

Tags: tomcat, docker, intellij-idea, web-deployment, remote-server

I'm trying to deploy my application to a tomcat server that is inside a docker container.
I'm using Intellj IDEA and I got it to work with the following:
- A tomcat remote connector with JMX configured and a shared folder between my pc and the container.

But I have one big problem, the context.xml that is located in the META-INF of my application is not deployed on the server although I have copyXML and deployXML

Intellj Idea allow me to copy a version of my context where it add a docBase balise but only inside my application.

How can i have my tomcat server copy or deploy my context.xml where I have my datasource defined ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In IDEA 16.3 and before, remote deployment to Tomcat ignores context.xml (this is covered by https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-150430).

It had been fixed for IDEA 17.1, so for this version the 'Remote staging' section of the Tomcat remote run configuration should have 'context.xml' sub-section with 'Path from root' field.

You may try to share the folder '<tomcat base>/conf/Catalina/localhost' from your Docker container so both this folder and staging folder will be locally under the same parent folder.

Then you should specify parent folder in the Remote staging -> Host settings, and relative paths to folders as 'Path from root' in 'context.xml' and 'Staging' sections respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I have declared webapps as a volume in my image and then I copy the content into into that folder when the container start.

So i end up with a mounted folder with my default webapps files.
But when i deploy the war and xml to the webapps folder with idea, it fails because my context is not deployed.
But if I just re start docker with my war and xml still in the mounted folder, then it works. And if re-deploy with IDEA to connect to my app with JMX it works too.

But it kind of suck and the static resources copy is not working for me because the path root is "webapps/../" and I don't find anyway to change it.

I don't get why it's so hard to have a hot deployment with IDEA on docker.

I guess I will have to go back to use the plugin remoteSynchronizer to copy .classes and resources to keep my webapp up to date but it's far from working as well as the FileSync plugin for Eclipse.